# this.node.contains does not work if this.node is a ref to react component

Tags: reactjs

There is XYZ component which I don't have access to. Now I want to detect
if that component is clicked.

```
render () {
   return(
    <XYZ className="abc" ref={node => {this.pop = node}} /> // Note, I don't have access to XYZ component
  )}
```

Reading through various articals I found this:

```
handleClickOutside(e){
    if (this.pop.contains(e.target)){
         // not clicked outside
    }
}
```

I am getting `Contains is undefined` as `this.pop` is a `React component`. How to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ReactDOM.findDOMNode to get a reference to the DOM node -

```
handleClickOutside(e) {
    if(this.pop) {
        const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.pop)
        if(this.pop.contains(e.target)) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Since findDOMNode is deprecated in React 16 and would be removed in future versions - another thing you can try is wrapping the XYZ component inside a div and check for click on that div.

```
render () {
   return(
    <div onClick={this.handleContainerClick}>
      <XYZ className="abc" ref={node => {this.pop = node}} /> // Note, I don't have access to XYZ component
    </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: EsLint gives warning that find dom not should not be used

Comment: would wrapping the XYZ element inside your own div help?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. It helped. I wrapped it in a div and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Fwiw, `findDOMNode` is _not_ deprecated and can be used in some scenarios. See Dan's answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9217#issuecomment-287622539).

Answer (score 6):

The current answer is to use the `current` attribute.

```
myRef = React.createRef();

const checkIfContains = e => {
    if (myRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

<div ref={myRef} onClick={checkIfContains} />
```

Comment: Try changing `<div>` to a React element, there will be an error that `current.contains` is not a function.

Comment: use forwardRef in that case